# How can I identify described structure within a directed graph

Tags: graphs

I am extending a gcc plug-in which should be able to detect branches within a loop, which can be run by speculation (run all branches in parallel and decide later what result to keep). The question is how to find the structures in the graph which are suitable.

For now the plug-in is only able to work with loops which have two branches like an if or and if/else construct.

Basically I am looking for structures within the graph which have a single entry and exit node.[image: structure I am looking for]

I had the idea to look for strongly connected parts in the graph.

Another idea is to use dominator relations since they are already available in the current plug-in.

The question for both approaches would be: are these approaches necessary or sufficient conditions (if suitable at all)?

Also any hints on different approaches I could have a look it would be appreciated. (e.g. Is there a name for a structure which can only be entered through a single node and exited through another?)

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You tell us what you're thinking of for potential solutions, but I'm not clear on what the problem statement is.  You ask if they're necessary or sufficient; necessary or sufficient for what?  If someone else proposed a solution, how should we evaluate it?

Comment: Can you define your problem more formally? It’s much harder to solve vaguely stated problems; often the OP changes the question upon understanding that it wasn’t posed properly, which is very annoying for anybody’s who has thought about the problem.